# Ubuntu 16.04 unable to recognize Wi-Fi network

Tags: 16.04

I dual booted Ubuntu alongside windows 10 a week  prior 
But Ubuntu is not detecting any Wi-Fi network or hotspots 
Any help would be appreciated

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 08 Jan 2017 17:56 IST +0530

Booted last: 08 Jan 2017 00:00 IST +0530

Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 0a)
    DeviceName: Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [103c:8216]

05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Intel Dual BandWireless-AC 3168 802.11 ac 1x1 WiFi + BT 4.0 Combo Adapter
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2110]

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0aa7 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05c8:038e Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

##### lsmod #############################

hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
wmi                    20480  3 hp_wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eno1' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:10.3.8.95  Bcast:10.3.11.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::9c2a:b1a:9f64:6a75/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:69884 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:41336 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:30206879 (30.2 MB)  TX bytes:3701908 (3.7 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.3.8.1        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eno1
10.3.8.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     100    0        0 eno1
10.4.20.201     10.3.8.1        255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 eno1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eno1

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search iiit.ac.in

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      2623     1  0 16:49 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eno1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'eno1' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:03:00.0/net/eno1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       eno1
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       8540577b-b01f-42ae-85a0-64f6c427f428
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   8540577b-b01f-42ae-85a0-64f6c427f428 | Wired connection 1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.3.8.95/22
IP4.GATEWAY:                            10.3.8.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 10.4.20.201/32, nh = 10.3.8.1, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             10.4.20.222
IP4.DNS[2]:                             10.4.20.204
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          iiit.ac.in
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.252.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 10.4.20.222 10.4.20.204
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 10.3.8.95
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        filename = /pxelinux.0
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 10.4.20.201
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       broadcast_address = 10.3.11.255
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       routers = 10.3.8.1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       wpad = http://proxy.iiit.ac.in/proxy.pac
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       domain_name = iiit.ac.in
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       expiry = 1483883176
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 10.3.8.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       next_server = 10.4.20.151
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       ntp_servers = 10.4.20.38
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 7200
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::9c2a:b1a:9f64:6a75/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

Sorry, try again.
[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wi-Fi connection 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Wi-Fi connection 1 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=OPPO A37f
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

eno1      no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eno1      Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   23.506613] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready
[   23.724047] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eno1: link down (repeated 2 times)
[   23.724127] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready
[   25.343820] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eno1: link up
[   25.343852] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eno1: link becomes ready
[  858.191902] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready
[  858.207851] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eno1: link down
[  858.207935] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready
[  858.207955] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eno1: link down
[  860.225364] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eno1: link up
[  860.225374] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eno1: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

http://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/

unable to install git and tree also should i install again

Comment: Windows recognized the Wi-Fi network

Comment: Run the wireless script in this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos). You can find the script in the accepted answer and paste the output in your question.

Comment: try `sudo rfkill unblock all` and then run `sudo iwconfig`. Edit your question if the output are different to the iwconfig section in your question. And edit the the lspci section as well, therefor run `lspci -nnk | grep -i "net" -A3`